# Spacy nl is not capitalizing the sentence correctly

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, spacy-3

I am using Spacy model and want to capitalize the plain text with the starting sentence and proper noun only.

I am using the code below

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_news_lg")
doc = nlp(text)
output_text = ""
for sent in doc.sents:
    for index, token in enumerate(sent):
        token_text = token.text
        if index == 0 or token.pos in (PROPN):
            token_text = token_text.capitalize()
        output_text += token_text + token.whitespace_
        
        output_text = output_text.strip() + " "
```

Now the error is like below
if index == 0 or token.pos in (PROPN):

```
TypeError: argument of type 'univ_pos_t' is not iterable
```

Is it possible to use this only for proper noun?

Comment: You are not looking for pronouns, you are looking for nouns and proper nouns.

Comment: so I have to add PRON as well to capitalize after full stop?

Comment: I tried. Still the start of sentence after fullstop . is not capitalize.

Comment: I have changed the settings and now I want only proper noun. But there is error. Is it possible to use only proper noun opt?

Comment: Do you just mean you need `if index == 0 or token.pos_ == 'PROPN':`?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```py
if index == 0 or token.pos_ == 'PROPN':
```

This line will check if either `index` is set to `0`, or if the current token POS is `PROPN`.